# Query for all rows where at least one child satisfies constraint 1 and all children satisfy constraint 2 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have a MySQL database with tables representing possible carpool routes. The three relevant tables are a carpool table (cardinality ~2 million), a carpool_stop table (cardinality ~11 million), and a trip table (cardinality ~300K). Trips represent a request to move from Location A to Location B. Carpools represent a possible route for a car to complete multiple trips at once by picking up users at multiple locations and dropping them off at multiple locations. Here are examples:
carpool:

```
+------------+-----------+
| carpool_id | completed |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         0 |
|          2 |         0 |
|          3 |         1 |
+------------+-----------+
```

carpool_stop:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| carpool_id | trip_id |  type   |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |       1 | pickup  |
|          1 |       2 | pickup  |
|          1 |       2 | dropoff |
|          1 |       1 | dropoff |
|          2 |       2 | pickup  |
|          2 |       3 | pickup  |
|          2 |       3 | dropoff |
|          2 |       2 | dropoff |
|          3 |       3 | pickup  |
|          3 |       4 | pickup  |
|          3 |       4 | dropoff |
|          3 |       3 | dropoff |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

trip:

```
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------+
| trip_id | carpool_id |    status     | pickup_date  |
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------+
|       1 | NULL       | 'INITIAL'     | '2019-04-01' |
|       2 | NULL       | 'INITIAL'     | '2019-04-02' |
|       3 | 3          | 'IN_PROGRESS' | '2019-04-03' |
|       4 | 3          | 'INITIAL'     | '2019-04-03' |
+---------+------------+---------------+--------------+
```

There is an index on trip.pickup_date.
The goal is to get all carpools that satisfy these conditions:

```
at least one trip has a pickup_date later than a specified date
AND 
(the carpool is completed OR 
(all trips have status in ('INITIAL', 'WAITING') AND have a NULL carpool_id))
```

In the example above, if the specified pickup_date was '2019-04-02', that would be carpools 1 and 3. Carpool 2 would not be returned since trip 3 is already part of a carpool and is 'IN_PROGRESS'.

I have a working query but it now takes 10 minutes to complete for a specified pickup_date that is only a day in the past because of the number of rows in the carpool_stop table.

```sql
SELECT carpool.*
  FROM (
     SELECT carpool_stop.carpool_id
        FROM trip
        JOIN carpool_stop ON carpool_stop.trip_id = trip.trip_id
        JOIN carpool      ON carpool.carpool_id = carpool_stop.carpool_id
        WHERE trip.pickup_date >= '2019-04-02'
        GROUP BY carpool.carpool_id
  ) AS inner_query
  JOIN carpool      ON carpool.carpool_id = inner_query.carpool_id
  JOIN carpool_stop ON carpool_stop.carpool_id = carpool.carpool_id
  JOIN trip         ON trip.trip_id = carpool_stop.trip_id
  GROUP BY carpool.carpool_id
  HAVING (sum(CASE WHEN (trip.status NOT IN ('INITIAL', 'WAITING') OR trip.carpool_id IS NOT NULL) 
                   THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                   END) = 0 
         OR carpool.completed = 1)
```

I am hoping for a way to write this query that is much faster, e.g. on the order of a minute or less.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the pickup_date column is indexed. If it isn't, then no matter what you do the query will be slow.

The main thing to keep in mind that most of the rows are history (trip.pickup_date < '2019-04-02'). So what you want is a query (or sub-query) that selects only the recent trips, then builds the rest of the query around that.

You did just that with your inner query so I'd say have the right idea. So why is it slow? Either pickup_date isn't indexed, or your query is written in a way that confuses MySQL from using that index. (MySQL's [`EXPLAIN` command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) can show if this is happening.)

There are ways to simplify the query. Just a few:

1. I don't think the inner query needs to join to the carpool table-- I don't expect a huge speedup from that though.
2. You could try writing the whole thing as two SQL statements, then use UNION. (That also gets rid of an OR, which can sometimes help.)
3. There are ways to get rid of the GROUP BY .. HAVING that may or may not help.

Alternatively: it seems to me that the query is returning carpools that are completed, plus carpools that haven't started yet. It might be simpler instead to test for all carpools that are in-between (i.e. carpool is not completed; but at least one trip has status picked-up or later.) If you try this, compare the results to your slow query to make sure they return the same results. There might be some obscure statuses to handle.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I edited the original post to point out that I do have an index on pickup_date. You are correct with Point 1 and it didn't make much of a difference. From looking at the EXPLAIN and experimenting, I've tried re-writing it using EXISTS, but am running into slowness from other parts of the query. I think a big part of the slowness in the current query is the join on carpool_stop of the outer query and then the GROUP BY.

Comment: Ok. What other indices are there? I would expect primary key indices on trip and carpool tables. Table carpool_stop (which doesn't have a primary key) should probably have two indices, on trip_id and on carpool_id.

Comment: Ideally the EXPLAIN will show that the inner query is running first and gets the number of rows way down before any part of the outer query runs.

Answer (score 0):

Based just on the title:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE     EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ... )      -- at least 1 child
      AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE NOT ... )  -- all (ie, none fail)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you need help in applying it to your data.